# is it possible to use "executor"in k6 options in default scenario? that is without specifiying "scenarios"

Tags: k6

I am experimenting with k6.
I want to know if
using executor in default scenarios is posssible?

my options object look like below. Note **"Executor"** property

```
    export let options = {
  vus: 1,
  duration: '1s',
  executor:'constant-vus'
}
```

when running k6 script i get Warning message *WARN[0000] There were unknown fields in the options exported in the script  error="json: unknown field "executor""*

the documentation doesn't say anything about using executors in "default scenario" so i am raising this question to the community.
please let me know[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `executor` property is only available inside scenarios. If you don't provide an `exec` function explicitly, the default function will be used.

```
export let options = {
  scenarios: {
    default: {
      executor:'constant-vus',
      duration: '1s',
      vus: 1
    }
  }
};

export default function() {
  console.log('this is executed once per second');
}
```

This is covered in the [`constant-vus` executor example](https://grafana.com/docs/k6/latest/using-k6/scenarios/executors/constant-vus/)

Note that `constant-vus` is the default when not using any scenarios and specifying duration and vus. So the above is equivalent to the following config:

```
export let options = {
  duration: '1s',
  vus: 1
};
```

Which is exactly the options from your question, minus the executor itself (but it still uses the constant-vus executor).